# Создание приложения для голосового звонка

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, voip, телефония

### Техническое задание

Необходимо создать сайт с одной единственной кнопкой **"Позвонить"**. После нажатия, пользователь на угад связывается с таким же пользователем, который нажал на эту кнопку и в ожидании. Затем они могут разговаривать, используя микрофон. Этот сервис для начала должен выдерживать разговор одновременно 10 000 пользователей и сразу необходимо заложить возможность в недалеком будущем создание мобильного приложения. Я так понимаю лучше сразу строить эту систему на микросервисах REST.

Я пока новичок в этой сфере и не знаю, как правильно это называется Интернет-телефония, IP-телефония или VoIP. Пока даже не понял, что из этого является частным другого.

---

### "Что говорит Google?"

**Термины**. Сразу конечно проблема с терминологией: по таким запросам как "voice chat" почему-то я в основном получаю ссылки на исходники по пересылке записанных аудио, т.е. не разговор в реальном времени, а как в современных мессенджерах предварительное записывание голоса с задерживанием кнопки микрофона. Если пишу "Интернет телефония" то тогда получаю ссылки по созданию приложений для звонка на мобильный телефон. Но мне не надо звонить на мобильный телефон, а необходимо связать два компьютера в интернете как это делает Skype и т.п.

**P2P**. Мне, я так понимаю лучше сразу обеспечить связь P2P между клиентами?

**.NET**. Как .NET разработчик мне конечно хочеться использовать в основе этот стек технологий или лучше использовать другой стек?

**XMPP**. Если можно так выразится, то часто предлагающее было использование для моих целей протокола XMPP (бывший Jabber).

**SignalR**. У меня есть небольшой опыт написание чата, где я использовал библиотеку SignalR и на мое удивление никто не предлагал использовать SignalR.

---

### Вопрос

Если попытаться спросить конкретно без слов "с чего начать", то мой вопрос звучит так: 
**Для начала мне бы хватил какой-нибудь маленький пример для разговора двух клиентов в локальной сети, ведь там у всех белые IP и скорость хорошая. Есть ли что-то готовое с чем я могу сделать прототип или библиотека/фреймворк с чего я могу менее безболезненно начать?**

Comment: _> исходники по пересылке записанных аудио, т.е. не разговор в реальном времени_ - Не существует разговоров в реальном времени. Прежде чем передавать звуковое сообщение его надо записать. Пусть хоть долю секунды, но задержка неизбежна.

Comment: Может попробовать просто сжимать аудиозаписи и передавать их одновременно с одного компа на другой, затем расшифровывать и проигрывать. При этом у приложения будет какое-время "синхронизации", когда настраивается оптимальная связь между компами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример собственного велосипеда о котором ты спрашиваешь, [можно найти здесь](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17048/Examples-to-create-your-Conferencing-System-in-NET).
В целом скоп задач, которые необходимо решить для разработки эффективной системы огромен, поэтому я бы на твоём месте смотрел исключительно в сторону готовых фреймворков. Большая часть из них строится на основе протокола [SIP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIP). Есть готовые [коммерческие продукты](http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/), есть [открытые](http://www.nongnu.org/partysip/partysip.html) и [гибридные](https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery). Выбирай то, что тебе подходит и вперёд.